# Transfer data between 2 classes without knowing the amount of data you are transfering nor their types

Tags: java, generics

I´m trying to transfer data between classes in a generic way. For example: I could transfer an Integer, String and a custom class Temperature in the same way I could transfer a Boolean, String, custom class Person and custom class Foo in a way that the class that receives the data could call a method of the Person class for instance.

I thought about doing it using Generics so that for each data I want to transfer I put it inside a DataWrapper that is generic so that I don´t lose the reference to any class but I want to send this data calling only one method (let´s say sendData()) using a class (let´s say DataSender) but since this DataSender needs to store all the generic DataWrappers that will have different generic values at runtime I must use the ? placeholder that will make me get an object instead of the specific reference when I retrieve the data from the class that receives it

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have a business application that I am developing with a small team, many modules of the User Interface communicate between each other so, for example, Window B will need some data from Window A in order to work properly so I want to create a generic way to send data between Windows without losing the original reference of the data (in order to call some subclass specific methods) in order to send data in a common and easy way

Comment: Use MVC pattern. Your UI should not be tightly coupled.

Comment: @PM77-1 what I mean is that, how can I do the controller to manage data fetching from the Model when the data fetching can get sometimes String, Integer and Foo and others String and Bar or any combination of types you can imagine?